# Finding unallocated key with emacs

Tags: emacs, key, elisp

I came up with a elisp function, and tried to match a key to the file.

```
(defun loadtopics ()
  "Load the topics.org file"
  (interactive)
  (load "../topics.org"))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-a") 'loadtopics)
```

The problem is it's hard to find an unallocated key combination.

- Is there any easy way to find key combinations that are not assigned?
- What method do you use for assigning the key to elisp code you made?
- Is it possible to assign multiple control key, i.e 'C-c C-a C-b C-x' or similar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The sequences beginning with <kbd>C-c letter</kbd> and <kbd>F5</kbd> through <kbd>F9</kbd> are reserved for users to rebind.  No built in modes or 3rd party packages should be overriding those, so they are perfect for user specific global key bindings.  See [Key Binding Conventions](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Key-Binding-Conventions.html) in the emacs manual.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an extra modifier key available, like <kbd>option</kbd> on the Mac or the Windows key on a PC, you can map it to the "super" or "hyper" modifier in Emacs and use it without fear of colliding with any built-in sequences.  For example, some of my key mappings that use super include:

```
(global-set-key [(super s)] 'shell)
(global-set-key [(super \\)] 'find-file-at-point)
(global-set-key [(super meta p)] 'emms-pause)
(global-set-key [(super ?!)] 'shell-command-with-?-expansion)
```

That last one is a command I wrote that works like `shell-command` except that it expands question marks in the command text into the full path to the current buffer, like `dired-do-shell-command` does.

Answer (score 2):

I've been meaning to try [this elisp library](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/unbound.el) for a while.

From the code's commentaries :

> The only entry point is `describe-unbound-keys'; it prompts for the maximum
>   ;; complexity to allow, which should probably be at least 5 to find enough
>   ;; keys to be worthwhile.  Lisp may call just`unbound-keys' to get a list of
>   ;; key representations suitable for `define-key'.